# shuffle rows of csv with python

Tags: python, csv

i would like to simply shuffle the rows of a csv file but keep the headers static.

contents of **unshuffled.csv**

```
Lastname  Firstname   Age

taylor    bob         40
mcdonald  kevin       32
smith     john        18
```

would like to output to **shuffled.csv** as below

```
Lastname  Firstname   Age
smith     john        18
mcdonald  kevin       32
taylor    bob         40
```

I am using code below, which was suggested in another post, but doesnt work for me.

```
from random import shuffle

with open('unshuffled.csv','r') as ip:
    data=ip.readlines()

    header, rest=data[0], data[1:]

    shuffle(rest)
with open('shuffled.csv','w') as out:
    out.write(''.join([header]+rest))
```

The output csv however shuffles data outside of the three columns as below.

```
Lastname  Firstname   Age
smith     john        18    32    kevin
taylor    bob         40
```

How can I make the columns static and just shuffle the rows in the csv file.

Comment: try `out.writelines([header]+rest)`

Comment: still get the same happening @Netwave is it something wrong with my csv file, like a missing carriage return ?

Comment: are you trying to get the results sorted by age? if so shuffle from random isn't the function you want

Comment: @arunkumar no i do not require any sorting, just for the rows of the csv to be shuffled into a different order so that row 1 may become row 3, and row 2 may become row 1 etc. The rows should remain under the same headers, however at the moment I get rows being put into new columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be missing the newline character on the last row of `unshuffled.csv`, so use something like this:

```
import random

with open('unshuffled.csv', 'r') as r, open('shuffled.csv', 'w') as w:
    data = r.readlines()
    header, rows = data[0], data[1:]
    random.shuffle(rows)
    rows = '\n'.join([row.strip() for row in rows])
    w.write(header + rows)
```

Comment: Perfect thankyou ! Yes i suspected it was missing some kind of carriage return, but couldnt figure out the best way to force it ! upvoted and answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
from random import shuffle

with open('unshuffled.csv') as ip:
    lines=ip.readlines()
    header = lines.pop(0)
    shuffle(lines)
    lines.insert(0, header)

with open('shuffled.csv','w') as out:
    out.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: still same problem @Mohammad Umair the rows are shuffled but not kept within the three header columns.